# MongoDB materialize records

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, twitter

I'm trying to iterate mongo db records and make an API request, when I do something like this:

```
const usersToFollow = await userStore.find({}).limit(10);

await usersToFollow.forEach(u => {
     console.log(`user: ${u.username}`)
})
```

this works fine and prints the records,  Now I'd like to make an API call for each record.
When I try to do this,

```
const userPromises = usersToFollow.map(u => {
    console.log(`user: ${u.username}`)
    return twitterClient.v1.createFriendship({ user_id: u.id})
});

await Promise.all(userPromises);
```

this doesn't work nor does putting an await before the call to map.  How can I chain an API call per mongo db record?

> userPromises is not an iterable

Comment: If all the MongoDB operations are successful, is this just a `twitter` API issue?

Comment: Sorry, the question was sloppy on my part, it saying that users promises is not iterable